# $scope.$emit in John papa style in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

```
  $scope.$emit("updateTabNames", equipmentTabName, customTabName);
```

how do i write this using John Papa's style guide i.e using "this" instead of $scope.

Comment: Do you mean the `controllerAs` syntax? You can't, functions such as `$on, $emit, $broadcast, $watch` exist only on the $scope

Comment: You can't. You have to use `$scope`.